# unable to import ’NLTK'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, nltk, chatbot

I’m currently working on my first chatbot and I need *nltk* for this bot to install. So I opened my terminal on my Mac and type `pip install nltk` and it successfully installs.

So I opened VisualStudioCode and I type `import nltk` but it replies: "Unable to import 'nltk‘ "

Why is this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It was bc I got the wrong version of python in vscose

Comment: Ha! I spent 2 hrs. trying to figure this out until I saw this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you select a python interpreter?
If this is not working you could try to install it from the command line in vscode

Answer (score 0):

try pip3 install nltk if you are using python3